# How to convert month name to month number using html-simple-dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom, codeigniter-3

Hello someone can help me? to convert month name to month number. Ok, let me explain. I use CI framework,  I make a web scraping, at the website have a date like this "21 NOVEMBER 2015" and I want to change the date/Posted_Date to be "2015-11-21" and store the date into my database. I don't know why when I scrap the date, the date  will be 1970-01-01.  here I show my Controller function.Please

```
public function UMKDATA()
{
    $data = array();
    $this->load->library('simple_html_dom');
    $this->load->model('Vtender_Data');
    // create HTML DOM
    $html = file_get_html("http://www.umk.edu.my/index.php/en/component/k2/item/180-tender-dan-sebutharga");
    // get title
    $strA = $html->find('.itemFullText tbody tr');

    $j = 0;   
    foreach($strA as $strB)
    {
        if($j >= 1)
        {
            $strB->innertext;
            $strC = str_get_html($strB->innertext);
            $masuk['Title'] = str_get_html($strB->find('td',1)->innertext)->find('span',0)->innertext;
            if($this->Vtender_Data->check($masuk['Title']) == 0)
            {
                $masuk['source'] = $strC->find('td',0)->innertext;
                //$masuk['Opening_Date'] = ($strC->find('td',2)->innertext);
                //$masuk['Posted_Date'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($strC->find('td',3)->plaintext));


                $date = ($strC->find('td',3)->innertext) ;
                //$date = str_replace('', '', $date);
                $masuk['Posted_Date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));


                //$masuk['Posted_Date'] = $strC->find('td',3)->plaintext;
                $masuk['Document'] = str_get_html($strC->find('td',4)->innertext)->find('a',0)->href;
                $masuk['URLNAME'] = 'UMK' ;
                $this->Vtender_Data->masuk($masuk);
            }
        }
        $j++;
    }

    $this->load->view('Admin/Home/header');
    $this->load->view('update_success');
    $this->load->view('footerLogin');

}
```

Comment: what format of date do you get from scrapped one ?

Comment: @Drudge format like this "Y-m-d"

Comment: so you want y-m-d format to store in db ??

Comment: yes and I want "21 NOVEMBER 2015" to be "2015-11-21"

Comment: why do you run an empty `foreach` on the first loop when `$j` is zero?

Comment: are you getting the right timestamp from $date?

Comment: @AdamZia Please check the below answer .

Comment: Your `$date` has three 'modes'. The value scraped from the site, the value after you use `strtotime()`, the value after performing `date()`. Did you check all those values individually? See if anything is out of sync. If they are all okay then your database query is wrong.

Comment: @RST because I want to read the website DOM

Comment: I don't think you understand what is happening. You are not reading the website DOM at that moment. You have `$j=0;` then you start the `foreach()`. The first thing in the `foreach()` is `if($j >= 1)` which at that point is not true as $j ==0. So your code skips the rest of the commands and just executes `$j++;` and performs the next `foreach()` which now will execute completely because `$j`is 1 or higher. Your first run is not doing anything, only increasing `$j`

Comment: $j= 0; is to declare 'j' variable if I not declare 'j' variable this function will be error because not defined variable: j . when i declare $j=0; then the function will start foreach() . then if ($j >=1) is depend on website what data in table I want.  this function is run perfectly i got the data I want but the error only at date.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code .

> It will take your date and convert it to unix timestamp first and the
>   [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function will convert it into the result that you want.

**strtotime — Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp**

```
$date = "21 NOVEMBER 2015";
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is the doc if you want to explore more. Hope it helps you . Happy coding :)

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but isn't this exactly the code he already has?

Comment: yes, this is correct output when we declare the $date, but the the problem is i read the date from website that why I use                                       $date = ($strC->find('td',3)->innertext) ;  this code to read the date from the website

Comment: if you can read the date then you can get the output as above answer isn't it ??

Comment: yes I can read but format date  at the website not same with db timestamp so when not same the data not insert correctly into db.